# Раскадровка для HTML5 переходим с AS3

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, actionscript, actionscript-3

Есть MoveClip из 100 frames. Как можно конвертировать в circle раскадровку? Чтобы применить в HTML5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант.. Пишем as3 скрипт, который каждый кадр добавляет на холст. И вот уже готовая раскадровка, остается только на css описание сделать.

Comment: как вариант конечно пойдет, но может есть онлайн конверторы?